# Probability for all epsilon is one implies for all epsilon probability is one

Tags: probability, convergence, probability-inequalities

I am struggling to work out if the following is true.

Let $\{A_\epsilon\}$ be an indexed set of events in a probability space. Does it hold that:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \mathbb{P}[A_\epsilon]=1 \implies \mathbb{P}\bigg[ \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} A_\epsilon\bigg]=1$$

If not, can I add any conditions (such as the $A_\epsilon$ are decreasing or increasing) to guarantee the result?

---

**Edit:** The origin of this question is from an almost sure convergence proof. The proof showed that:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \mathbb{P}[\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } |X_n-X|\leq \epsilon]=1$$

but then the proof just jumped to:

$$\mathbb{P}[\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } |X_n-X|\leq \epsilon]=1$$

and that confused me a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by this notation?

Comment: I, too, cannot make any sense of the right hand side.  I am expecting the probability to be of an *event,* but what event is "$\forall \epsilon\gt0,A_\epsilon$"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was thinking in term of logic events "for all epsilon, $A_\epsilon$ happens" - I realise this was bad notation and I've changed the notation.

Comment: Technically, you should answer this question first:  given $A_\epsilon \in \mathscr{F}$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, can you guarantee that $\cap_{\epsilon > 0}A_\epsilon \in \mathscr{F}$?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding: suppose the probability space is the real interval $(0,1)$ with the uniform measure and that the indexing set for $\epsilon$ is also $(0,1),$ where $A_\epsilon = (0,1)\setminus\{\epsilon\}$ (the interval with the number $\epsilon$ removed). Notice that $\Pr(A_\epsilon)=1$ for all $\epsilon$ but $\cap A_\epsilon$ is *empty.* Would this be a valid example of what you are asking about?

Comment: Ah, right - assume that $\cap_{\epsilon>0}A_\epsilon \in \mathcal{F}$... the origin of this question is from an almost sure convergence proof. The proof showed that:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \mathbb{P}[\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } |X_n-X|\leq \epsilon]=1$$

but then the proof just jumped to:

$$\mathbb{P}[\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } |X_n-X|\leq \epsilon]=1$$

and that confused me a lot.

Comment: It is always much, much better to ask the question you really have!

Comment: I'm sorry @whuber! :/ I will add these comments into the question text!

Comment: Yes, that would be a valid example of what I was talking about - thank you that has convinced me it does not hold. Do you know if there are any conditions under which it holds, potentially that cover the almost sure example?

Comment: You need the index set to be at most countable.  The proof is a direct application of the probability axioms and the sigma-additivity of the probabilities.

Comment: I see... thank you... couldn't it be the case that the indexes are uncountable but both sides are still well defined though? What if $A_\epsilon$ were increasing so that $\epsilon\leq \epsilon' \implies A_\epsilon\subseteq A_{\epsilon'}$? I could then define $B_n=A_{1/n}$ and both sides would be well defined with countable indexes.

Comment: Sure, both sides are well defined (see my example).  The problem is that your result doesn't necessarily hold, because the probability axioms tell you *nothing whatsoever* about uncountable intersections.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for your time @whuber! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement from the proof in the edited part of the question has $A_{\epsilon_1}\subset A_{\epsilon_2}$ for $\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2$. This means that the intersection can be written as countable intersection for, say, $\epsilon\in\{\frac{1}{n}\ :\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. For countable intersections, the statement holds, see  [Countable intersection of almost sure events is also almost sure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100570/countable-intersection-of-almost-sure-events-is-also-almost-sure)

The result will generally hold for increasing or decreasing sequences, as here the countable intersection is the same as the uncountable one.

Comment: I see that this has been already almost completely done in the comments to the question. I have only realised this after writing the answer, but of course it makes sense to have this as an answer anyway.

Comment: No this is really helpful! Thank you @Christian Hennig! This was what I was looking for!